# Calculate Manhattan Distance return Category with lowest distance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I'm looking to create a function that calculates the Manhattan distance between a selected category and all the other categories in a dataset. The function should then return the CATEGORY with the lowest distance from the selected.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size= (10,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['category']= ['apple','orange','grape','berry','strawberry','banana','kiwi','lemon','lime','pear']
```

The code below returns the smallest 4 distances which includes the selected category (distance = 0; which is redundant and not needed). I need the code to only return the lowest 3 distances as a list of categories, the first being the smallest.

```
def distance(row):
    cols = list('ABCD')
    return (df[cols] - row[cols]).abs().sum(axis=1)

df.set_index('category', inplace=True)
dist = df.apply(distance, axis=1)

dist['apple'].nsmallest(4)
```

For instance, if "Apple" was selected, and the three lowest distances from Apple were Berry, Orange and Grape, return should look like this: ["Berry", "Orange","Grape"]

Comment: please, don't forget to check with the green tick if any solution solves your issue. This helps the community know which issues are solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the function [`cityblock`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cityblock.html) from `scipy.spatial.distance`:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

df.set_index('category', inplace = True)

>> df.apply(lambda x: distance.cityblock(x, df.loc['apple',:]), axis=1
        ).drop('apple', axis=1).nsmallest(4).index.values.tolist()

 ['strawberry', 'berry', 'kiwi', 'orange']
```

Basically, you get the distance from each row to the one selected. Then you drop the row containing the selected label and pick the index of the smallest distances.

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size= (10,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['category']= . ['apple','orange','grape','berry','strawberry','banana','kiwi','lemon','lime','pear']
df.set_index('category', inplace = True)
```

It's a mouthful but:

```
lowest_3 = [df.index[pd.Series([abs(df.loc[ind1] - df.loc[ind2]).sum() for ind2 in df.index]).argsort()[1:4]].tolist() for ind1 in df.index]

lowest_3_series = pd.Series(lowest_3, index = df.index)

lowest_3_series['apple'] = ['banana', 'lemon', 'grape'] # Results will differ due to randomness obviously
```

This will get you a list of the lowest 3 values for each value in df.index.

For instance, the first element of this list is your solution for `'apple'`

Explanation:

First, you create a list comprehension for each index in df.index. This nested list comprehension is an iterations over df.index again. You call df for this index and compare them all pairwise (making n^2 comparisons total) . You compare each index by taking the absolute value between their column values and summing them. Then turn this list into a series and use`argsort` to fetch the first 3 (excluding the reflexive comparison which is always 0). Then you call df.index on this slice of indices, which gets you the names of these lowest 3 values.